# push second or more array into array object angularjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

```js
angular.module('print', []).
controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.settingData = [{
    "currency": "RM",
    "fields": {
      "type": "",
      "cost": "",
      "pax": "1"
    }
  }]

  $scope.addNewFields = function() {
    var row = $scope.settingData.length;
    if (row < 3) {
      $scope.settingData.push(row);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="print" ng-controller="Ctrl ">
  <button ng-click="addNewFields()">Add</button>
  <br />
  <br />
  <div class="editSection">
    <div class="inputRowWrap" ng-repeat="data in settingData">
      {{data.fields.type}} {{data.fields.cost}} {{data.fields.pax}}
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col col-40">
          <label class="item item-input">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Room Type #{{$index+1}}" ng-model="data.fields.type">
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col col-40">
          <label class="item item-input">
            <input type="text" placeholder="RM" ng-model="data.fields.cost">
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <select ng-model="data.fields.pax">
            <option>pax</option>
            <option value="1">1 pax</option>
            <option value="2">2 pax</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="padding saveBtnWrap">
      <button ng-click="saveSetting()">Save</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I manage the push to add the new html but the new input is not working, I guess I've failed to add a new array object to my existing array object.

Comment: Do array `push` and `pop` considered as solutions?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (row < 3) {
    $scope.settingData.push(row);
}
```

You push an integer into an array of objects. I've updated your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mkcegb80/1/

Comment: wow is this a usual way? return a function into an object, this is first time I see..

Comment: Depending what you mean by usual :). When you use `new`, javascript creates a new object for you (function is an object too). If you just call the function without `new` then it will return the same instance of the initial object. It's cleaner to use `angular.copy` as Vinay K suggested.

Answer (score 0):

instead of pushing the index into the array, we need to push an object.

```
angular.module('print', []).
controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
  var data = {
    "currency": "RM",
    "fields": {
      "type": "",
      "cost": "",
      "pax": "1"
    }
  }

  $scope.settingData = [angular.copy(data)]

  $scope.addNewFields = function() {
    var row = $scope.settingData.length;
    if (row < 3) {
      // create a copy of the data object and push into the array
      $scope.settingData.push(angular.copy(data));
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: great stuff, have to learn more about copy(), any alternative that is easier to understand?

Comment: copy is a function which creates a deep copy of the object passed to it.

Comment: cannot do like assign object to $scope.settingData and then do angular.copy($scope.settingData)?

Comment: No, our list over which we iterate should have unique items. Cloning the settingData will create another array. We need only one array with multiple elements in this case.